# Can you please identify in which case following error occurs in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created one xaml page with binding but at sometimes at time of page loading getting fallowing exception, it seems very strange.

Please suggest in which situation we can get this type of error.

Error:
[image]

Comment: Have you bound the `Orientation` property of your `StackLayout`?

Comment: Thanks jesus, yes of course but there is no need to mention orientation property for stacklayout. If we doesn't mention anything it will take vertical orientation right? Then what was the problem with that. Can you please tell me.

Comment: Please can you include your XAML ?

Comment: I think it's difficult to do that, it's nearly 800 line of code in my xaml page.

Comment: Maybe, the relevant part? where you show us your StackLayout binding and where it is from(viewmodel).

Comment: Yes I have bind the values from viewmodel. It doesn't point out any line, so i am not able to find out relevant area for cause of exception.